# Apparently JSON.parse is faster than declaring an object literal. If that's the case, why are my results showing otherwise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, performance

According to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ff4fgQxPaO0) released on the Google Chrome Developers YouTube channel, `JSON.parse` is actually faster than an object literal.

I decided to put that to the test, and my results heavily favour object literals, time and time again.

See here: https://jsperf.com/testing-obj-literal-vs-json-parse/1

Also see here: https://gist.github.com/lucaschen/ef0bb733f638563140b6bb0d374f3691 (you can run this in Node.js)

My results consistently show object literal parsing as taking about 75% **less** time than `JSON.parse`.

Is the video wrong, or are my tests not a fair representation of the scenario outlined within the video?

Answer (score 5):

At small-scales, `JSON.parse` is **not** faster than using object-literals in JavaScript. You're misunderstanding the claims made in the video - it's better to read the original article at https://v8.dev/blog/cost-of-javascript-2019#json

Here's the important part:

> A good rule of thumb is to apply this technique for objects of 10 kB or larger — but as always with performance advice, measure the actual impact before making any changes.

Comment: I've read the original article, which is why my Gist involved the parsing of a 70kB JSON string. However, I've realised that this discrepancy is likely caused by the fact that declaring an object in a `for` loop likely invokes some internal caching. I'm rewriting the test to prevent this from happening, I'll see how that goes.